# error assigning a function pointer passed as an argument in the constructor to a private instance variable

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, function-pointers

I'm trying to assign a function pointer that is an argument in the constructor of a class to a private instance variable.  (The purpose of this is to be able to pass a callback function to the constructor and use said callback function in member functions of the class.)

I thought I declared the instance variable correctly as a function pointer.  The way I read the code snippet, the left operand "cmp" is a pointer, not a function, just like the right operand.  (Both are pointers to functions of the same type, or so I thought.)  However, the error message says "function as left operand."  What am I doing wrong or misinterpreting?  Is there a "most vexing parse" issue somewhere?

How can I fix this error and assign the function pointer?

I'm getting the following error message:
"error C2659: '=' : function as left operand"

The error is occurring in the following snippet of code:

```
template <typename Type>

    PQueue<Type>::PQueue(int (cmpFn)(Type,Type))
    {
        cmp = cmpFn;
    }
```

The compiler is complaining about

```
cmp = cmpFn;
```

The constructor prototype is

```
PQueue(int (cmpFn)(Type, Type) = OperatorCmp);
```

(OperatorCmp is just another function pointer.)

I declared the instance variable in the private section as

```
int (cmp)(Type, Type);
```

The IDE I'm using is Visual C++ 2008 Express, if that matters. (using old version to be compatible with old course materials).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration

```
int (cmp)(Type, Type);
```

indeed declares a function, not a function pointer. However, the same syntax used in the parameter list for a function declaration denotes a function pointer, so `cmpFn` is in fact of type `int (*)(Type, Type)`. Just change the declaration for `cmp` to

```
int (*cmp)(Type, Type);
```

and you'll be good.

Comment: Now I'm confused :) Didn't you say previously that `(cmp)` decays to a function pointer, so in principle you should be able to assign a function pointer to it, in the same way you can write `array=pointer`?

Comment: @vsoftco When and where did I say this?

Comment: @vsoftco, what I said was that if you declare a function parameter to have function type, it gets adjusted to a function pointer. So `cmpFn` gets adjusted. On the other hand, `cmp` is not a parameter, so it doesn't get adjusted.

Comment: @vsoftco, a function also decays to a function pointer when it's assigned to or used to initialize another function pointer. (This is a *standard conversion*.)

Comment: Ok, but the OP is saying this: `cmp = cmpFn; //error here`. `cmp` is the parameter of the ctor, declared as `int (cmpFn)(Type,Type)`, and `cmpFn` is a function pointer of type `int (*)(Type, Type)`. Now, I am doing the exact same thing in my code, assigning to parameter `void x()` a function pointer `void (*)()`, and the compiler doesn't complain. I may misunderstand something here.

Comment: @vsoftco: You can't have a function on the left-hand side of an assignment. However, you can have a function pointer (if it's a modifiable lvalue, blah blah). If you have `void x()` as a *parameter* then `x` is in fact a function pointer, not a function.